# Pine Script Code is Slow on low Timeframes

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

My code is taking time to load on low timeframes(240,60,15). I don't have much knowledge on Arrays and For loops, I have created this code with the help of a Stackoverflow thread(Box Update feature using loops), and also I would like to limit the box count using user input, Kindly help me with this issue.

````
maxbox = 500
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
indicator("Liquidity Zones",overlay=true,max_boxes_count=maxbox)
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

VolBars = input.bool(true, title='ON/OFF  ', tooltip='Colored Bars based on Average Daily Trading Volume (ADTV)', inline='2',group="Volume Bars")
VolLen  = input.int(10, title='Volume Length', minval=1, inline='2',group="Volume Bars")

Volume = nz(volume)
Volume2 = Volume*(high-low)
HighVOL = ta.highest(Volume2,VolLen)

VolAvg  = math.sum(Volume, VolLen) / VolLen

IncreasingVol1 = VolAvg * 1.5
IncreasingVol2 = VolAvg * 2

bool BullCandle = close > open
bool BearCandle = close < open

Color      = Volume >= IncreasingVol1 or Volume2 >= HighVOL  ?  1 : 0

//Box condition
ColorCode  = Volume >= IncreasingVol2 or Volume2 >= HighVOL  ?  2 : Color

color BullColor  = ColorCode == 1 ? #208000 : ColorCode == 2 ? #008000 : color.new(#8c8c8c,0) 
color BearColor  = ColorCode == 1 ? #801a00 : ColorCode == 2 ? #e60000 : color.new(#8c8c8c,50)

color BarColor   = BullCandle ? BullColor : BearColor

barcolor(VolBars ? BarColor : na,editable=true)
plotchar(Volume > VolAvg * 3.5, char='', size=size.tiny,editable=false)

color BullBoxColor  = ColorCode == 1 ? #208000 : ColorCode == 2 ? #008000 : na
color BearBoxColor  = ColorCode == 1 ? #801a00 : ColorCode == 2 ? #e60000 : na

//Box Color
BoxColor = BullCandle ? BullBoxColor : BearBoxColor
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
look_back_period = input.int(100,title="Max Bars")
switchs = input.bool(true,title="Live Update Zones")

var box[] Bull_box = array.new_box(look_back_period)
var box[] Bear_box = array.new_box(look_back_period)

int size_array0 = 0
int size_array1 = 0

size_array0 := array.size(Bull_box)
size_array1 := array.size(Bear_box)


if ColorCode and BullCandle
    
    
    array.push(Bull_box,box.new(left=time, top=close, right=time, bottom=open, extend=extend.right,
     xloc=xloc.bar_time,border_color=na,bgcolor=color.new(BullColor,80)))

if size_array0 > 0
    
    for i = 0 to size_array0 -1
        
        t = box.get_top(array.get(Bull_box, i))
        b = box.get_bottom(array.get(Bull_box, i))
//Delete Box        
        if  b >= low 
        
            box.delete(array.get(Bull_box,i)) 
//update Box
        if switchs and t >= low
        
            box.set_top(array.get(Bull_box, i),low)

if ColorCode and BearCandle
    
    array.push(Bear_box,box.new(left=time, top=open, right=time, bottom=close, extend=extend.right,
     xloc=xloc.bar_time,border_color=na,bgcolor=color.new(BearColor,80)))
     
   
if size_array1 > 0    
    
    for i = 0 to size_array1 -1
        t = box.get_top(array.get(Bear_box, i))
        b = box.get_bottom(array.get(Bear_box, i))
//Delete Box        
        if  t <= high
        
            box.delete(array.get(Bear_box,i)) 
//Update Box
        if switchs and b <= high 
        
            box.set_bottom(array.get(Bear_box, i),high)
            

//END-///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////```
````

Comment: you can use the bar replay function for understanding the indicator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//@version=5

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
indicator("Liquidity Zones",overlay=true,max_boxes_count=500)
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

VolBars = input.bool(true, title='ON/OFF  ', tooltip='Colored Bars based on Average Daily Trading Volume (ADTV)', inline='2',group="Volume Bars")
VolLen  = input.int(10, title='Volume Length', minval=1, inline='2',group="Volume Bars")

Volume = nz(volume)
Volume2 = Volume*(high-low)
HighVOL = ta.highest(Volume2,VolLen)

VolAvg  = math.sum(Volume, VolLen) / VolLen

IncreasingVol1 = VolAvg * 1.5
IncreasingVol2 = VolAvg * 2

bool BullCandle = close > open
bool BearCandle = close < open

Color      = Volume >= IncreasingVol1 or Volume2 >= HighVOL  ?  1 : 0

//Box condition
ColorCode  = Volume >= IncreasingVol2 or Volume2 >= HighVOL  ?  2 : Color

color BullColor  = ColorCode == 1 ? #208000 : ColorCode == 2 ? #008000 : color.new(#8c8c8c,0) 
color BearColor  = ColorCode == 1 ? #801a00 : ColorCode == 2 ? #e60000 : color.new(#8c8c8c,50)

color BarColor   = BullCandle ? BullColor : BearColor

barcolor(VolBars ? BarColor : na,editable=true)
plotchar(Volume > VolAvg * 3.5, char='', size=size.tiny,editable=false)

color BullBoxColor  = ColorCode == 1 ? #208000 : ColorCode == 2 ? #008000 : na
color BearBoxColor  = ColorCode == 1 ? #801a00 : ColorCode == 2 ? #e60000 : na

//Box Color
BoxColor = BullCandle ? BullBoxColor : BearBoxColor
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
max_levels = input.int(100,title="Max Levels", maxval = 250)
switchs = input.bool(true,title="Live Update Zones")

var box[] Bull_box = array.new_box()
var box[] Bear_box = array.new_box()

int size_array0 = array.size(Bull_box)
int size_array1 = array.size(Bear_box)


if ColorCode and BullCandle
    array.push(Bull_box,box.new(left=time, top=close, right=time, bottom=open, extend=extend.right,
     xloc=xloc.bar_time,border_color=na,bgcolor=color.new(BullColor,80)))
    if array.size(Bull_box) > max_levels
        box.delete(array.shift(Bull_box))
    
if size_array0 > 0
    
    for i = 0 to size_array0 -1
        if i <= array.size(Bull_box) - 1 and array.size(Bull_box) > 0
            t = box.get_top(array.get(Bull_box, i))
            b = box.get_bottom(array.get(Bull_box, i))
//Delete Box        
            if  b >= low 
        
                box.delete(array.remove(Bull_box,i)) 
//update Box
            else if switchs and t >= low
        
                box.set_top(array.get(Bull_box, i),low)

if ColorCode and BearCandle
    
    array.push(Bear_box,box.new(left=time, top=open, right=time, bottom=close, extend=extend.right,
     xloc=xloc.bar_time,border_color=na,bgcolor=color.new(BearColor,80)))
    if array.size(Bear_box) > max_levels
        box.delete(array.shift(Bear_box)) 
   
if size_array1 > 0    
    
    for i = 0 to size_array1 -1
        if i <= array.size(Bear_box) - 1 and array.size(Bear_box) > 0
            t = box.get_top(array.get(Bear_box, i))
            b = box.get_bottom(array.get(Bear_box, i))
//Delete Box        
            if  t <= high
        
                box.delete(array.remove(Bear_box,i)) 
//Update Box
            else if switchs and b <= high 
        
                box.set_bottom(array.get(Bear_box, i),high)
```

Comment: Thank You so much, It's perfectly working, Arrays are still tricky for me and I'm trying to learn this. I understood the changes you have made. Thanks for the quick help.

Comment: Hello, I have noticed that the box is not printing on the very first candle. including other random candles, attached are screenshots for your reference. can you please look into this, Thank you.
https://www.tradingview.com/x/Cv2K8SFh/
https://www.tradingview.com/x/bOU2ekfX/

Comment: You'll just need to remove `max_levels` from the two  box array declarations, so it is just `var box[] Bull_box = array.new_box()`. I think what was happening is, instead of removing the na element from the array, it was removing the oldest actual box element, so if there was only one (like on the first bar that has a box), it was adding it and removing it on the same bar.

Comment: This one fixed the glitch now, Thank you, I tried the bar replay function previously, the box was not printing for those candles, other candles are printing the boxes and deleting once criteria are met.  Still confused with arrays and the stored values within an array :) Thanks for the help.